# Помогите настроить веб сервер для деплоя webhook телеграм бота

Tags: telegram-bot, nginx, веб-сервер, развертывание

Всем привет! Изучаю java и параллельно пишу pet проект - вебхук телеграм бота.
Для отладки локально использовал ngrok для получения адреса вебхука - все было норм. Однако когда пришел черед развернуть на собственном сервере - не взлетело. Помогите разобраться где ошибка и как это исправить.

Итак, имею vps от Timeweb. Там же крутится предыдущий бот, но без вебхуков - работает исправно.

На сервер получил SSL ключи через certbot

```
root@1559973-ci01275:~# ls /etc/letsencrypt/live/1559973-ci01275.twc1.net
cert.pem  chain.pem  fullchain.pem  privkey.pem  README
```

Настроил следующим образом nginx:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;  
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;  
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name 1559973-ci01275.twc1.net;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/1559973-ci01275.twc1.net/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/1559973-ci01275.twc1.net/privkey.pem;

        location /webhook {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_redirect off;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Content-Length $http_content_length;
        }

        ssl_ciphers 'TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384';

        ssl_ecdh_curve X25519:prime256v1;

        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem;
    }
}
```

Отключил uwf:

```
root@1559973-ci01275:~# ufw status
Status: inactive
```

Задал endpoint для вебхука в коде

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/webhook", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Успешно зарегистрировал свой вебхук

```
ok  true
result  true
description "Webhook was set"
```

Однако, бот глух к командам...
https://api.telegram.org/.../getWebhookInfo дает следующее:

```
ok  true
result  
url "https://1559973-ci01275.twc1.net/webhook"
has_custom_certificate  false
pending_update_count    1
last_error_date 1702289241
last_error_message  "Wrong response from the webhook: 404 Not Found"
max_connections 40
ip_address  "89.223.121.78"
```

В логах nginx:

```
User
2023/12/11 02:33:49 [crit] 985841#985841: *2991 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A00006C:SSL routines::bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 170.64.188.15, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2023/12/11 04:49:26 [crit] 985841#985841: *3035 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A00006C:SSL routines::bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 74.82.47.4, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2023/12/11 05:07:18 [crit] 985841#985841: *3051 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A00006C:SSL routines::bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 212.102.40.218, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2023/12/11 06:31:29 [crit] 985841#985841: *3079 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A00006C:SSL routines::bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 118.26.39.120, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2023/12/11 07:08:44 [crit] 985841#985841: *3104 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A00006C:SSL routines::bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 2001:470:1:c84::18, server: [::]:443
2023/12/11 10:21:16 [crit] 985841#985841: *3139 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A00006C:SSL routines::bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 167.94.138.35, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2023/12/11 11:27:34 [emerg] 1524786#1524786: unexpected end of file, expecting "}" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:107
2023/12/11 11:29:37 [warn] 1524918#1524918: conflicting server name "1559973-ci01275.twc1.net" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
2023/12/11 11:29:47 [warn] 1524932#1524932: conflicting server name "1559973-ci01275.twc1.net" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
2023/12/11 11:29:47 [warn] 1524933#1524933: conflicting server name "1559973-ci01275.twc1.net" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Решение №1

Правильная настройкка поддержки SSL в SpringWeb:

1. Получить SSL через let's encrypt и certbot:

   ```
   sudo certbot certonly --standalone -d yoursite.com
   ```
2. Создать keystore.p12:

   ```
   openssl pkcs12 -export -out keystore.p12 -inkey privkey.pem -in fullchain.pem
   ```
3. в application.properties добавить:

   ```
    Server settings
    server.port=443
    server.ssl.enabled=true
    server.ssl.protocol=TLS
    server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSv1.2
    server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
    server.ssl.key-store=${keystorePath}
    server.ssl.key-store-password=${keystorePassword}
   ```

где

- `${keystorePath}` - путь к созданному `keystore.p12` (при расположении в папке resourses проект - достаточно указать `classpath:keystore.p12`
- `${keystorePassword}` - пароль от `keystore.p12`

Минус этого решения в том, что порт 443 будет занят нашим ботом.

### Решение №2

Правильная настройка nginx:

1. Указать в application.properties локальный порт

   ```
    #Server settings
    server.port=localPort
   ```
2. Получить SSL для nginx через let's encrypt и certbot:

   ```
   sudo certbot --nginx
   ```
3. Создаем конфигурационный файл по пути

   ```
    /etc/nginx/sites-available/yoursite.com/nginx.conf
   ```

со следующим содержимым:

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name yoursite.com;

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/yoursite.com/cert.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/yoursite.com/privkey.pem;

location /webhookLocation {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:localPort;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

4. Перезапускаем nginx:

   ```
    sudo systemctl nginx
   ```